# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6' in QT Quick

Tags: python, qtquick2

I have problem that everything works perfectly in Visual Studio Code, but in QT Quick im still getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\qt\kurs1\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6'
```

What can be caused of this error? How to fix it?

Comment: Is it possible that the module PySide6 is not appended to the sys path?
Or is the module in the folder the main.py it is getting launched?

Try to use sys.path.append(('/path/to/application/app/folder') to be sure that module will be reachable at right time.

Comment: how to check it?

Comment: It might be that the python installed for the Visual Studio has already that module in the path. 
Instead the QT Quick when is getting executed, cannot locate that python module.

Comment: Python error is telling easily that the module you want to use cannot be located, nor in the default path, neither among the appended path (if any). Thus it is trowing correctly the exception.

Comment: You must have (at least) two different installations of Python on your computer.  QT Quick is using one, and VS Code is using another.  Show us the output of this code in both QT Quick and VS Code `import sys; print(sys.path)` And please put that output in the question, not here as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that the module PySide6 is not appended to the sys path? Or is the module in the folder the main.py it is getting launched? Try to use

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/application/app/folder')
```

to be sure that module will be reachable at right time.
That should solve your issue in my opinion. (as you mentioned in the comment that module is already installed for your python --> pip install module)

Hi Szymon, let's try a possible solution....step by step from me :-)

Open CMD (command line from windows) and go to that path you have:
`cd 'C:\\Users\\szymo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312'`

Then go to "Scripts" folder with command --> `cd Scripts`

Then write --> `pip install PySide6`

That will either tell you already installed, or will install for the python version you are using in your program :-) As per output you have above, that module will be now found :-)

Comment: thats my python code:
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


sys.path.append('D:\python\qt\kurs1')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    qml_file = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "main.qml"
    engine.load(qml_file)
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec())

it does not work

Comment: Do you know where the module needed is located? Then before you try to run the app/engine just do a sys.path.append('your_module_path').
That will solve the issue.

If the module is missed on your pc then you can even try to install from the windows prompt using the pip install module_name. That might also help in your case.

Comment: I saw from the other comment that you already install, then please try to add the sys.path.append line. That will solve the issue ;) as the module will be for sure located

Comment: Please have a look also at existing post like --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder That is also explain what I wrote before.

Comment: i already added sys.path.append('D:\python\qt\kurs1') and it does not work...

Comment: That means in the 'D:\python\qt\kurs1' is the module located (in one children folder or in that folder itself). 

So after the import, even a 'import PySide6'  should fail as the module won't be find ;) 
Are you sure that module is in there? Can you print(sys.path) as well?

Comment: output of print(sys.file): ['d:\\python\\qt\\kurs1', 'C:\\Users\\szymo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.zip', 'C:\\Users\\szymo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\szymo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\szymo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312', 'C:\\Users\\szymo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages']

Comment: Question is: is it really the module located under 'd:\\python\\qt\\kurs1'? It looks like the path was successfully appended, but you need to have the PySide6 module below that path

Comment: In addition watch out...that is exactly the initial problem! You appended now successfully the path, but the module file is not located under 'd:\\python\\qt\\kurs1'.
Please add the path where the PySide6 resides on your pc. That would really fix the issue.

Comment: Hi Szymon, let's try a possible solution....step by step from me :-)
Open CMD (command line from windows) and go to that path you have: 
cd 'C:\\Users\\szymo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312' 

Then go to "Scripts" folder with command --> cd Scripts
Then write --> pip install PySide6

That will either tell you already installed, or will install for the python version you are using in your program :-)

As per output you have above, that module will be now found :-)

Comment: Happy to hear that :-) Please close the question and enjoy the evening. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

To use a module, first, you need to download it. In this case, before running the codes, you need to install PySide6 module via CMD. Just open CMD then run this line `pip install PySide6`. It will solve your problem.

Comment: like i said, VSD works okay, i have already downloaded PySide6 by pip, but it still does not work